# Find synonyms from a paragraph of a given word using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im fetching the word for which the synonyms has to be found from input box. The synonyms for the word should be from another text and if found it should be displayed.

Comment: Provide some code please.

Comment: Please provide more detail about your question. ie. What are the input and the expected output? Any method you have already try?

Comment: suppose there are 2 text area in one there is written a paragraph, other has input field which once filled with word should find all the synonyms from the above text field. Data in text area are dynamic can be changed

Answer (score 0):

You need to map all words to it's synonyms, then just search/replace words.

```js
var synonyms = {
  'car': [
    'vehicle',
    'motorcar',
    'truck'
  ],
  'door': [
    'entrance',
    'opening',
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
    var text = $('p').text();

    if (typeof synonyms[$(this).val()] !== 'undefined') {

      $.each(synonyms[$(this).val()], function() {
        text = text.replace(this, '<span>' + this + '</span>');
      });
    }

    $('p').html(text);
  });
});
```

```css
p span {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter word 'car' or 'door'" />

<p>
  opening vehicle cat truck pineapple red entrance
</p>
```

---

Check out this [synonyms page](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/)