# Passing keywords using the Search Function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML table with a Search function that works well. Additionally, I am passing keywords using a Javascript object. The problem with keywords is that it searches for exact matches. What can I do to make the keyword contains instead of exact match. My example below passes the keyword "Apple Banana". However, I only get results after searching the entire term "Apple Banana". Is there a way to search for "A" or "App" and get the results. If using object is not the best approach, I am open to any other suggestions.
Note that the HTML table is generated automatically by the Content Management System and I am not able to manipulate it. I can only update Javascript or CSS file.

```js
const obj = {
  'Apple Banana':'ABC',
};
function myFunction() {
  let userInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  if(obj[userInput]) userInput = obj[userInput];
  userInput = userInput.toUpperCase();
  const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
  for (let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    const rowTextContent = tableRows[i].innerText.toUpperCase();
    tableRows[i].style.display = rowTextContent.toUpperCase().includes(userInput) ? "" : "none";
  }
}
```

```css
table.table_brdr td {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border: none;
}

table.table_brdr th {
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
  color: black;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color#D3D3D3;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search forms list" title="Search forms list"></p>
<table class="table_brdr" id="myTable">
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th><strong>Column2</th>
<th>Column3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>abc</td>
<td>xyz</td>
<td>03/30/2017</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>test12</td>
<td>https://www.yahoo.com/ </td>
<td>03/30/2017</td>
</tr>
  
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th> New Column</th>
<th>Column3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>abctd <td>
<td>09/30/2019</td>
</tr>
  
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th> New Column2</th>
<th>Column3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>abctd </td>
<td>06/30/2019</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Is there a way to make Javascript object contains

Comment: if I understand correctly, you are trying to find the synonyms of the word? maybe check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506238/find-synonyms-from-a-paragraph-of-a-given-word-using-javascript

Comment: Basically, what you can do is after displaying your result based on the user input, check for the synonyms in the object and display the result again using the synonym

Comment: I am new to JavaScript. I tried but it doesn't seem to work. Is it possible for you to create an example for my test case? Thanks